# extract Apple ID's password from mavericks keychain?

Tags: macos, mac, keychain

First of all i need to know if mail's passwords stored in keychain or not ?
If yes .. how to extract passwords from keychain especially [APPLE ID] ?
That's it

Comment: Assuming you use gmail, open the key chain and type imap.gmail in the search to find it.

Comment: With regard to your edit, the procedure is the same for Apple IDs as the procedure detailed for the linked question. If you have any problems with this, feel free to edit your question to be specific to this problem you are facing in following the guidance in the aforementioned question.

Answer (score 1):

Open up Keychain Access, located in /Applications/Utilities/.  A list of all your stored credentials are listed in categories on the left.  I typically search for a credential by either the application it is associated with, or by the username.

[image]

Double click on the credential you desire to obtain the password for.  A window pops up and there is a check box towards the bottom to Show the Password.  Check the box, you'll be required to type in admin credentials, and it'll show you the password it has saved.

[image]

These instructions can also be found [here](http://www.creativetechs.com/iq/retrieve_forgotten_passwords_with_keychain_access.html)

Comment: @Buscar웃, only if he's using gmail with IMAP.

Comment: Thanks alot guys for that info .. But what if i don't remember my admin password .. What if i want to decrypt keychain and extract passwords from it .. Is that possible ?

Comment: @MohamedShibo what would be the purpose of decrypting if you could go around it and bypass that?

Comment: to view password of Apple ID which not possible to view using that way Flying Trashcan suggested .. !!

Comment: You asked about retrieving Mail passwords, not Apple ID.

Comment: So, i've to ask a new question about extracting Apple ID password from keychain .. !!??

Comment: Did you start a new question, or are you changing this question?  If the latter, please reflect the change the original question.

Comment: This has been changed.